# Building an Ionic app with Xcode, how can I see the .js files in the archived app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

To publish an Ionic (v1) app to the app store, I have built it via Xcode and done an 'archive' operation. Then, I sent the app to apple from Xcode.

I am trying to use the cordova-uglify plugin, and I wish to check that it is doing its work. So, I'd like to find the .js files that reside on the archived file (i.e., on the file.xcarchive that I sent to apple)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`cordova-uglify` plugin runs on `after_prepare` hook. This means it will do its job when you run `ionic build {platform_name}`.

In you case, after successful `ionic build ios` command, check `platforms/ios/www/` directory. By default, your JS file(s) would be under `js` folder. Open and see if you JS files are minified. If so, then your archive will have minified files.

Comment: Xcode uses the www folder at root of the project not from the platform directory. So finally it is not included on the app